# Projection from $\mathbb{R}^2$ with dictionary ordering and ordered topology to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

First, we assign $\mathbb{R}^2$ the dictionary ordering. Then, I am tasked to consider two projections from $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the ordered topology to $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology:
$$p_a(x,y) = x $$
and
$$p_b(x,y) = y. $$

I want to study these projections and see if

1. if the projections are continuous;
2. if the projections are open; and
3. if the projections are closed.

I know that I can show a function from $X \xrightarrow{} Y$ to be continuous by showing that, for every open subset $V$ of $Y$, the preimage $f^{-1}(V)$ is also open in $X$. (And similarly, that for every closed set $W$ in $Y$, the preimage $f^{-1}(W)$ is closed in $X$.)

However, aside from that I'm completely stumped by this problem and am unsure where to even start. Any suggestions/hints as to where to begin would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at the intervals in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with respect to dictionary order.

Let $x = (x_1, x_2)$ and $y = (y_1, y_2)$. We have:
\begin{align}
(x, \infty) &= \{x_1\} \times (x_2, \infty) \ \sqcup \ (x_1, \infty) \times \mathbb{R} \\
[x, \infty) &= \{x_1\} \times [x_2, \infty) \ \sqcup \ (x_1, \infty) \times \mathbb{R} \\
(-\infty, y) &= \{y_1\} \times (-\infty, y_2) \ \sqcup \ (-\infty, y_1) \times \mathbb{R} \\
(-\infty, y] &= \{y_1\} \times (-\infty, y_2] \ \sqcup \ (-\infty, y_1) \times \mathbb{R} \\
(x, y) &= \{x_1\} \times (x_2, \infty) \ \sqcup \ (x_1, y_1) \times \mathbb{R} \ \sqcup \ \{y_1\} \times (-\infty, y_2) \\
(x, y] &= \{x_1\} \times (x_2, \infty) \ \sqcup \ (x_1, y_1) \times \mathbb{R} \ \sqcup \ \{y_1\} \times (-\infty, y_2] \\
[x, y) &= \{x_1\} \times [x_2, \infty) \ \sqcup \ (x_1, y_1) \times \mathbb{R} \ \sqcup \ \{y_1\} \times (-\infty, y_2) \\
[x, y] &= \{x_1\} \times [x_2, \infty) \ \sqcup \ (x_1, y_1) \times \mathbb{R} \ \sqcup \ \{y_1\} \times (-\infty, y_2]
\end{align}

Open sets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are unions of open intervals. Infinite intervals are also unions of finite intervals, so actually, open sets are unions of finite open intervals.

Because the closure of a closed set is open, it follows that closed sets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are intersections of the sets of the form $(-\infty, x] \sqcup [y, \infty)$.

---

We will only consider $p_a$. Arguments needed for $p_b$ are essentially the same.

1. To show that $p_a$ is continuous, we need to show that the preimage of a finite open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ is open. Let $V = (a, b) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. We have $U = p_a^{-1}(V) = (a, b) \times \mathbb{R}$. To show that this is an open set, let $x \in U$. It is easy to see that $x \in (y, z) \subseteq U$ where $y = ((a + x_1)/2, 0)$ and $z = ((b + x_1)/2, 0)$. This shows that $U$ is an open set. Therefore $p_a$ is continuous.
2. Let $x = (1, 0)$ and $y = (2, 0)$. We have $U = (x, y) = (1, 2) \times \{0\}$ and $p_a(U) = \{1\}$ which is not open, so $p_a$ is not an open map.
3. Let $G = (-\infty, x] \sqcup [y, \infty)$. We have $p_a(G) = (-\infty, x_1] \sqcup [y_1, \infty)$ which is closed, so $p_a$ is a closed map.